# Pointing to a property without reflection or databinding

Tags: c#, pointers, reflection

I want to create a class with a property that "variably" points to some other property in another class.

Imagine a class (called "Limiter") with several integer properties (Limit1, Limit2, etc).

I now want a second class ("LimitWatcher") which can "watch" one of those limits. But I want to be able to set *which* particular limit it is watching in the constructor. I eventually want several instances of LimitWatcher, each one pointing to a separate Limit. The Limit values themselves may change after the Watchers have been instantiated, but the watcher must always see the current value of the Limit that it is watching. So basically, I want to store a reference to an integer.

I know I can accomplish this using reflection (see example below), but I feel as though there might be a simpler way.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Limiter 
    {
        public int limit1 { get; set; } = 10;
        public int limit2 { get; set; } = 20;
        public void Update()
        {
            limit1++;
            limit2++;
        }
    }
    public class LimitWatcher
    {
        public LimitWatcher(Limiter lim, string propName)
        {
            myLimiter = lim;
            limitName = propName;
        }
        private Limiter myLimiter { get; }
        public string limitName { get; set; }
        //can I do this without reflection:
        public int FooLimit { get { return (int)typeof(Limiter).GetProperty(limitName).GetValue(myLimiter); } }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Limiter lim = new ConsoleApplication4.Limiter();
            LimitWatcher w1 = new LimitWatcher(lim, nameof(lim.limit1));
            LimitWatcher w2 = new LimitWatcher(lim, nameof(lim.limit2));
            lim.Update();
            Console.WriteLine($"1st watcher sees {w1.FooLimit}");  //11
            Console.WriteLine($"2nd watcher sees {w2.FooLimit}"); //21
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to pass name? Why not `Func<Limit, int>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Func int the constructor, something like:

```
private Limiter limiter;
private Func<Limiter, int> propertyAccesor;

public LimitWatcher(Limiter lim, string propName, Func<Limiter, int> propertyAccesor)
{
    this.propertyAccesor = propertyAccesor;
}

public bool LimitExceeded()
{
     int propertyValue = propertyAccesor(limiter);
     return propertyValue > 20;
}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to figure out how to instantiate the propertyAccessor, but I worked it out: `propertyAccesor = new Func<Limiter, int>(L => L.limit1));`

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic expressions:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class LimitWatcher
{
    public LimitWatcher(Limiter lim, string propName)
    {
        myLimiter = lim;
        limitName = propName;

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Limiter), "x");
        var member = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);
        var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Limiter, int>>(member, parameter);
        getter = finalExpression.Compile();
    }

    private Func<Limiter, int> getter;

    private Limiter myLimiter { get; }
    public string limitName { get; set; }

    public int FooLimit { get { return getter(myLimiter); } }
}
```

Inspired by this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically)

Comment: this looks helpful, but its slightly more than I needed. Thanks for the good suggestion & link, though!

Comment: Slighlty more error susceptible because propName could have any value as long as there is no guarantee it will be called always using nameof, but could have its uses.